# Highlight an area based on postal code [Google Maps]

Tags: google-maps, web, vector, maps

I need to show a newspaper reach on my website based on postal codes. I have read that Google Maps doesn't have an API for it, so I tried to find some alternatives.

However, I found nothing. So I am asking you, what would be the best and fastest thing to do in this situation? Are there any vector maps that have the administrative boundaries already made? And that can be connected with postal codes?

[image]

[**Google maps example of what I need**](https://www.google.dk/maps/place/2610+R%C3%B8dovre/@55.6894495,12.4171612,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x465251139c8bfc63:0x7b1a945eb7597269!8m2!3d55.6889548!4d12.4492456?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your purpose is marketing. On your website, you want people to see the coverage area / newspaper reach, so you only need images. Here is an answer, according to that assumption.

I suggest you make the exact images that will work best for you. (This is a common job for designers on many web development teams, and if you are having trouble creating high-quality images, I'm sure you can find someone who is skilled with it.)

Using Google ([example search](https://www.google.com/?q=map+creator)), you can find various free web applications that allow you to annotate maps. Save or [screenshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot) your images and post them on your website.

Alternatively, using Google Maps, you can search for your postal code and screenshot the results. If you have multiple codes, you'll need to use an image editing program to combine them.